# Closing connection and unsubscribing from DataReceived handler

Tags: c#, serial-port, eventhandler

I have an application that receives the data from an external laboratory unit trough a serial port. When I try to close the SerialPort, I get the following error:

> System.IO.IOException: 'The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.'

The data is read in event handler, raised by `SerialPort` event `DataReceived` - this runs in a separate thread by default (AFIK).

I subscribe to the `Eventhandler` when connection to a `SerialPort` is being established.

I unsubscribe from the `EventHandler` before I close the serial port.

Code to close the connection (where `_chronosPort` is an instance of a `SerialPort`):

```
public void CloseConnection()
{
    if (_connected)
    {
        _chronosPort.DataReceived -= OnDataReceived;
        _chronosPort.Close();
        _connected = false;
     }
 }

private void OnDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
     var sp = (SerialPort) sender;
     RawSample = sp.ReadTo("\r");
     SampleFactory sampleFactory = new SampleFactory(RawSample, new SampleTypeExtractor());
     OnSampleReady(sampleFactory.GetSample());
}
```

When invoking the `Close()` method, I get:

> 'The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.'

The error is thrown from `EventHandler`'s `SerialPort ReadTo()` method, even though have unsubscribed from the event handler just before closing the serial port.

Comment: Are you opposed to checking `_connected` in the `OnDataReceived`?  Simplest way would be to set `_connected = false` before closing and return in the handler if it is not true.

Comment: Felix,
I have tried and it simply did not work in my case. I'll check again if I have implemented the suggestion correctly. For now, the solution suggested by @Baddack works fine, except it doesn't solve the situation where '\r' does not appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are using `SerialPort` `ReadTo`, the `ReadTo` is blocking until it see's a character in the buffer stream you specified.  So when you go to close the port, the `ReadTo` is still waiting for a `\r`.  Unsubscribing isn't enough, as it's still running on it's own thread.

The fix would be to use `ReadExisting()`, which will return all the characters in the buffer immediately.  However, this will require more logic on your side in which you'll have to look for that end character yourself.  Below is a simple way to use `ReadExisting`, I build the string until I see my end character then I parse the string:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    string Data = serialPort1.ReadExisting();

    foreach (char c in Data)
    {
        if (c == '\r')
        {
            sb.Append(c);

            CurrentLine = sb.ToString();
            sb.Clear();

            SampleFactory sampleFactory = new SampleFactory(CurrentLine, new SampleTypeExtractor());
            OnSampleReady(sampleFactory.GetSample());
        }
        else
        {
            sb.Append(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly how I used to read data in the past, before I learned that ReadTo() method exists. This also explains why ReadTimeOut is firing TimeOut, even if the buffer was read using ReadTo('\r').
I have also noticed that ReadTo('terminationCharacter') does not include the terminationCharacter in the output string, so the '\r' was not included in the resulting line.
Cheers!